# The system $A^Ty\le0,A^Ty\ne 0$ has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

$A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. Suppose that the following system has no solution:$$Ax=0, x>0$$
Then the following system has a solution:$$A^Ty\le0,A^Ty\ne 0$$

**My attempt**:
First I supposed on the contrary that for all $y$ then $A^Ty\not \ge0$ and 
if $A^Ty\le0$ then $A^Ty=0$. By this assumption is tried to find a vector $x>0$ such that $Ax=0$, but I got stuck.
Then I tried to manipulate the first system into a form the fits into the Farkas' Lemma and then to use the lemma, again with no success.

Aby ideas?

Comment: Hint: and equivalent way to express $x>0$ here is to write $x\ge\mathbb{1}$, the vector of all ones.

Comment: See Theorem 2.5f in [my *Elementary derivations of some results of linear optimization*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/linopt.pdf), with the caveat that the $y$ in my Assertion S2 is your $-y$ (because $A^T y \leq 0$ is equivalent to $\left(-y\right)^T A \geq 0$, and because $A^T y \neq 0$ is equivalent to $\left(-y\right)^T A \neq 0$). This is called Stiemke's theorem. I derive it from Gordan's theorem (Theorem 2.5e), which in turn I obtain from one of the separation theorems (Theorem 2.1c); I hope you have already proven one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a partial solution using Farkas' Lemma:

The system

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
Ax=0\\x>0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

has a solution iff the system

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
Ax=0\\x\geqslant\mathbb{1}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

has a solution iff the system

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
Ax=0\\x-s=\mathbb{1}\\x,s\geqslant0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

has a solution. The final system is equivalent to the system

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\I&-I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\s\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\mathbb{1}\end{bmatrix}\\
x,s\geqslant0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Apply Farkas' Lemma to this system and see if you can get it.

Comment: I don't think this is true to write that if $x>0$ then $x\geq1$

Comment: @convxy $x>0$ does not directly imply $x\geq1$, but if there exists $x$ such that $Ax=0$ and $x>0$, then for any scalar $\alpha>0$, we have $\alpha{Ax}=0$ and $\alpha{x}>0$. In particular, we can choose $\alpha$ large enough so that $x\geq1$.

Comment: I think better way to write it is if $x>0$ then exist $s>0$ such that $x-es\geq0$

Comment: @convxy I phrased it as “system A has a solution iff system B has a solution iff system C has a solution.” The solution to each system may not be the same